# Django Rest Serializer Foreign Key Is Required Error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am trying to have a client have a 1 to many relationship with emails and phones.

```
class Client(models.Model):

class Email(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='emails')
    email = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)

class Phone(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='phones')
    phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
```

And this is my serializer

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = EmailSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True, many=True)
    phones = PhoneSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True, many=True)
```

I cannot pinpoint why the post will not proceed because it keeps saying client is required.

While i got it to work by adding read_only=True, even if i define a def create(self, validated_data) in the ClientSerializer i cannot get hold of the emails and phones array in the json data.

This is how I called the serializer in the views.py

```
serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
```

This is how the json data looks like

{"id":0,"emails":[{"id":0,"emailType":"Home","email":"test@gmail.com"}],"phones":[],"name":"me"}

So my goal is if in the emails array, if there is an email property, insert it, otherwise ignore. same as phones.

This is how i called the serializer in views.py

```
@api_view('POST'])
def client(request):
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

So inside ClientSerializer, i create the client object via
Client.objects.create(validated_data);

Then extracted the emails array from the validated_data and did a for loop.
for (ed in emailData):

```
Created an email = Email() object then
email.email = emailData.get('email')
email.client = client
```

But it gives me an error "null value in column "client_id" violates not-null constraint". When i do a print(email), the client object from email.client is null which is weird, considering print(client) has an id.

Thoughts?

Comment: What do your serialisers look like ? What about the data you POST ?

Comment: that is what my serializer looks like. i editted the post to include the sample json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're serializing a model (`Client`) which expects a FK. If you want that to support null values, you should do in your model:

```py
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='emails', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: hi higor. thank you for the tip. I tried this, the problem now is that when i print self.data the emails/phones array are None. but if i just print self, it will print the ClientSerializer with the json data that includes the emails and phones array..

Comment: Maybe you should print `self.serialized_data`?

Comment: following your tip, i removed read_only=True and i can now get the data. I am just confused though, why did that work, setting null and blank to true? considering that the foreign key should not be null.

Comment: If you don't want the FK to be nullable you need to send the id for the client in your payload to the view.

Comment: i have some progress. when i get the json data, i extract the emails array. Create a client object first, then assign those data to an Email object and then setting email.client = client (the created client object). but it gives me an error "null value in column "client_id" violates not-null constraint". It is weird because the client object has an id, i verified it. but the email object when print() has the client as null even afteri assigned it.

Comment: Please, update your question with all the information you're describing here so we all can see in a "code stylistic" way. It's way easier to help that way, thanks

Comment: hi. sorry. editted more code. it's not the complete one coz i am afk now, just snippets of it.

Comment: finally got it to work. i had to pass the json array data to the context so that in def create it can extract those because validated_data will not return those arrays to None.